# I am trying to render two renderlayers, but the second layer black background is on top of the first layer

Tags: workflow, blender-internal-render-engine, compositing-nodes, render-layers

So, I followed some tutorials and modeled planet Earth and an asteroid. Because it's two different compositions I separated each one in a different render layer. But only the asteroid layer is rendering properly, and the planet is not showing. I don't know what I am doing wrong, so I think is easier if you guys check it out if you can.

[Here's the .blend](https://mega.co.nz/#!s0Bl1KKb!cADYrwfSZCa_HBIJ6iJssdLhxLKbg7EMaUdxZXHc__w)

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

[Blend with packed textures](https://mega.co.nz/#!QpRziQ5Q!UyYsjiN4h7ZVF9IPDNIPnXKFWS5S5TVAKYc6k766nQE)

Comment: @poor The link is working now

Comment: @ifsando Your .blend seems to be working fine for me.. Note that your compositing tree doesn't combine the renderlayers, but aside from that I don't see anything amiss (there are some missing textures, but I imagine that's just because they weren't packed with the .blend)..

Comment: @ifsando the same here as gandalf3

Comment: Oh right.. Didn't think about it. Here I think this should work:           https://mega.co.nz/#!QpRziQ5Q!UyYsjiN4h7ZVF9IPDNIPnXKFWS5S5TVAKYc6k766nQE                         The asteroid layer has a black background that is rendering on top of the earth layer after composition. In this file I tried to fix that by putting an alpha over node. But it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *lens distortion* node is making all the pixels in the asteroid layer opaque so that the alpha over covers up the earth layer.

The solution is to do the lens distortion after combining the layers:

[image]

The lens distortion should be done after combining layers anyway, as with a real lens everything in the image is distorted.